# Android Error Simple (2 Activities)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-install-apk

I have 2 activities:
I am just getting input from 1st activity and posting into 2nd.

In my first activity, I have :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBoxFirstActivity);  
    String message = editText.getText().toString();                        ----Line 1
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);                                -----Line 2
    startActivity(intent);
```

where SecondActivity is a java file for 2nd activity.
textBoxFirstActivity is the ID of EditText in 1st one.

In SecondActivity.java, I have :

```
Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String msg = intent1.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(msg);                                        


    setContentView(textView);
```

See Above, there are 2lines - Line 1 and Line 2. When I delete Line 1 and pass a Static String to Line 2 instead of "message", it works. But, it's of no use.
Please explain why this code is not working.

Comment: try to print message in log..and see what value it is getting..and r u getting any error

Comment: App crashes and it says - "Application failure detected please try again"

Comment: you are launching intent from oncreate..

Comment: Sorry not to tell you that- there is a button in 1st activity and on onClick, a method is working (which is in 1st activity.java file) which is 1st code I have written above. And, 2nd code portion is in onCreate of the 2nd activity

Comment: pls post error/logcat message

Comment: please post the onCreate method for your secondActivity

Comment: also, try adding a log to see what 'message' is (between line1 and line2), and post your logcat and code